# Converting a List of String Type To Decimal Type List

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting, casting

I Have a `List<MyClass> MyList`
Where `MyClass` Description is

```
 public class MyClass
    {
        public Nullable<decimal> Id { get; set; }
        public string Marks { get; set; }
        public string rank { get; set; }
    }
```

Items in MyList

```
Id  Marks Rank
1   100   null
2   15    null
3   5     null
4   55    null
5   51    null
6   12    null
7   32    null
```

Here Type Of `Mark`s Is `String` Therefore If I try To `Sort/OrderBy` It by Marks It Gives me wrong Sort order
Is There any Way From which i convert the type Of Marks Column From **String --> Decimal**

Comment: I realise this is bad (and probably has corner cases that I haven't thought of).. but you could "technically" do this too: `var newList = list.OrderBy(x => x.Marks.Length).ThenBy(x => x.Marks)`. It orders by the lengths of the strings.. then by their value. I wouldn't really recommend it though.. but thought I'd put it out there.

Comment: Thanks,for your valuable answer @SimonWhitehead It is So nice solution

Comment: Side note: `Id` as `decimal`? This is quite strange and unusual. Do you really expect something like `3.14` as `Id`?

Comment: its just an example @AlexeiLevenkov btw i'll keep it in my mind next time

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Although your solution is really appreciable but it consist a drawback As i mentioned i want to convert my column from string to Decimal So if Marks is in the form of 25.75 your Solution got failed

Comment: Hence "edge cases I haven't thought of" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to prepare another class, with proper property type:

```
public class MyClass2
{
    public Nullable<decimal> Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Marks { get; set; }
    public string rank { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use LINQ to convert one list into another:

```
var newList = source.Select(x => new MyClass2
                                 {
                                     Id = x.Id,
                                     Marks = decimal.Parse(x.Marks),
                                     rank = x.rank
                                 }).ToList();
```

Or you can do the ordering without changing the property:

```
var orderedList = source.OrderBy(x => decimal.Parse(x.Marks)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the property of mark to decimal

```
public class MyClass
{
    public Nullable<decimal> Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Marks { get; set; }
    public string rank { get; set; }
}
```